# How to get a value on a page using jquery and echo it onto the page using php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

**Problem:**

I need to get the number 65 in strong tag.
I tried the following code, but it shows Uncaught ReferenceError.
(I'm a newbie and I spent for hours to create the following code but ended up like this...)
Would you please let me know how to fix this problem?

**Code I tried:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
var getnum;
getnum = $('div.elementor-widget-container p > strong').text();
<?php $abc = "<script>document.write(getnum)</script>"?>   
});
</script>
<?php echo $abc;?>
```

**Console error:**

Uncaught ReferenceError: getnum is not defined
**HTML (code came from a yith point & reward plugin):**

```
<div class="elementor-element elementor-element-c1d0790 elementor-widget elementor-widget-text-editor" data-id="c1d0790" data-element_type="widget" id="pointsid" data-widget_type="text-editor.default">
    <div class="elementor-widget-container">
        <p>Your credit is  <strong>65</strong> Points</p>                       
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you

Comment: Where did the number 65 come from? Doing what you are doing, wouldn't the user simply be able to edit the HTML to whatever credit they want?

Comment: Hi Bolli: The code came from a yith point & reward plugin, and the points changes for different users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing up `javascript` and `php` together. You could pass variables from server-side (i.e `php`) to client-side (i.e `javascript`) but not the other way around! At least not on the same page without using `ajax`. You could do it with `ajax`, but you're not using `ajax` here. There are some tricks however, which are not recommended for the production.

Also it's worth mentioning that your question is not clear why you would want to do it like that.

You would not get any error, if you write your code like this:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    let getnum = $('div.elementor-widget-container p > strong').text();
    console.log(getnum);
  });
</script>
```

Which will give you `65` in the console. However, you want to echo it out using `php`.

The following "tricks" are NOT recommended for the production:

- You could use "localStorage" in order to store your value and retrieve it again!
- You could use "cookies" too!

So your code would be something like this:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    let getnum = $('div.elementor-widget-container p > strong').text();
    localStorage.setItem("getnum", getnum);
  });
</script>

<?php echo "<script>document.write(localStorage.getItem('getnum'));</script>"; ?>
```

Which will echo `65` onto the page using `php`!

Let me know if that was what you were looking for!

---

Tested and works fine!

Comment: Hi Ruvee: Wow, thanks a lot for your detaled explanation and supportive hlep. I've learnt a lot from you as always, and I votied up and selected your answer : ) . I changed localStorage.setItem("getnum", getnum); to  localStorage.setItem('getnum', JSON.stringify(getnum); and it shows the number "65" now. Thanks again. And... I was wondering if you could teach me one more thing? The result shows "65". Would you please teach me how to get the value without  " " ?  So that it only shows 65.  Thank you Ruvee : )

Comment: Not a problem! Happy to help. You do not have to use `JSON.stringify` for a single string value. I had tested the code before I posted it here and I made sure everything worked. I tested it on wordpress `5.8.1` and ran it on both `firefox` and `chrome` browsers. So the code you see above works fine. Again, you do not have to use `JSON.stringify` for a single string value **BUT** if you want to use `JSON.stringify`, then make sure when you get the value back you use `JSON.parse` to get the value without `""` quotations. Like this:  `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('getnum'))`.

Comment: Also, remember, you're setting a value to a user's browser, which means that user has access to that value which means s/he can manipulate the value. Just something to keep in mind!!!

Comment: Hi Ruvee: Thanks again : ) Your JSON solution works very well (I'm not sure why but  it shows no value without the JSON on my side, so I tried it ...) ... And.. thank you for your heads up, can I ask  a quick question? Ummm... Does it mean users can edit their woocommerce points and it will actully change the points of the admin side if they want?

Comment: Anytime!!! Well, they can manipulate the value while it's in the local storage on the client-side not the server-side. But remember not to rely on that number if you want to update something on server-side later on.

Comment: Ahh, yep, I get it now, you are a big help as always, thank you thank you : )

Comment: FYI, here's [a reference link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage#example) which indicates that your single string value does not need to be `JSON.stringify`ed!

Answer (score 0):

Getnum is defined when the document is loaded. When you access getnum, it is not yet declared.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Frenzy.